# Placing -g switch in configure.ac gives error with libtool

Tags: c++, makefile

C++ Makefile Project
I am trying to modify the code STREAM http://infolab.stanford.edu/stream/c...m-0.6.0.tar.gz . This code is a Makefile C++ code which generates Library.
My problem is that when I try to use gdb it gives me error
"stream-0.6.0/net_server/src/net_server": not in executable format: File format not recognized"

Then i tried to place -g in configure.ac then executed make. Afterwards libtool gave huge number of errors. How to use gdb so that i can trace it step by step to understand the code.

Comment: The link does not work. Modifying `configure.ac` just before running `make` should make no difference since the makefile is generated by `configure`. What's your os? What does `file stream-0.6.0/net_server/src/net_server` output? Are you able to run it directly? What does `which gdb | xargs file` output?

Comment: Sorry somehow link got corrupted the corrected link is http://infolab.stanford.edu/stream/code/stream-0.6.0.tar.gz . The configure.ac is                                                                                           
dnl CXXFLAGS='-g -ansi -Wall -D_MONITOR_ -D_DM_ -D_SYS_STR_'
CXXFLAGS='-ansi -D_MONITOR_ -O3 -D_SYS_STR_'
so as when i change place -g in front of the second line of CXXFLAGS then error starts occurring.

Comment: My problem was solved by using CXXFLAGS='-g -O0 -ansi -D_MONITOR_ -O3 -D_SYS_STR_' in configure.ac file.

Comment: Hmm, so what differs is: the presence of `-O0` but that seems to be useless since it gets overwritten by `-O3`; and the absence of `-Wall` but that also shouldn't make a difference either since it suppresses some warning messages (unless `-Werror` is also passed to the compiler from some other place in the Makefile).